# Removing trailing characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, strip

I thought that this code below could remove the trailing character of every element in a. I can't understand the output

```
a = ['wonderland@', 'alice,', 'in!$', 'book:']

for index, word in enumerate(a):
    for ch in '@!$,:':
        a[index] = word.strip(ch)
print(a)
```

```
>>>['wonderland@', 'alice,', 'in!$', 'book']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Recommended:

Try `rstrip` this way with a list comprehension:

```
a = ['wonderland@', 'alice,', 'in!$', 'book:']
print([i.rstrip('@!$,:') for i in a])
```

Or try `regex`:

```
import re
print([re.sub('[@!$,:]+$', '', i) for i in a])
```

Both codes output:

```
['wonderland', 'alice', 'in', 'book']
```

### Not recommended:

The reason your code doesn't work is because you may well matched the character(s) at the end but the next iteration you would be still trying to strip from the original string, instead of the string that you just stripped in the previous iterations. Also you use `strip` so it might be that only one character would be striped, so you also need to use `sorted`, so to fix your code:

```
a = ['wonderland@', 'alice,', 'in!$', 'book:']
for index, word in enumerate(a):
    for ch in sorted('@!$,:', key=word.find)[::-1]:
        a[index] = a[index].strip(ch)
        print(a)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['wonderland', 'alice', 'in', 'book']
```

Comment: @U12-Forward I actualually want to return every word back in the list after removing the trailing characters

Comment: @O'BrienZimeTaga Edited my answer

Comment: @O'BrienZimeTaga Added an explanation of why your code doesn't work :)

Comment: @JohnKugelman Added an explanation and fix

Comment: Your use of `sorted` is really a hack.  I like your other two solutions better.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oh yeah haha, I edited my answer to specify the good ones

Comment: "but the next iteration it would be reassigned back". That isn't why the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: No, it isn't part of the reason at all. Your working fix (although highly inefficient) also matches the character(s) at the end and in the next iteration it would be reassigned back.

Comment: @blhsing My code wouldn't work without using `a[index] = a[index].strip(ch)`, and instead using `a[index] = word.strip(ch)`

Comment: I see your point now, although that sentence doesn't quite make that point. That explanation should read something like "because you keep stripping from the original string instead of the stripped string from the previous iteration".

Comment: @blhsing Ah I clarified a bit more about that. Edited my answer, thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're iterating over the list and assigning it to `word`, then every call to `strip` starts over with the unmodified `word`.  Try this instead:

```
for index in range(len(a)):
    for ch in '@!$,:':
        a[index] = a[index].strip(ch)
```

And it turns out that doesn't work either, because it's dependent on the order of the characters that you're removing.  Take advantage of `strip`s ability to remove multiple characters at once.

```
for index in range(len(a)):
    a[index] = a[index].strip('@!$,:')
```

Comment: That doesn't work... that gives `['wonderland', 'alice', 'in!', 'book']`

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: @U12-Forward yes I did, but not until after I posted it.  I discovered the problem probably about the same time you did.

Comment: Yeah while I was editing in the reason I tested the code and realized it... Anyway wouldn't of figure that out if I didn't test it :D